# Selection sort - python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

I can't seem to make my selection sort work. Any idea whats wrong? When run it gives me [5,6,3,1]

Thx!

```
aList = [1,5,6,3]

def selection_sort( aList):
    for i in range(len(aList)):
        min = i
        j = i + 1
        for j in range(len(aList)):
            if aList[j] < aList[min]:
                min = j
        swap(aList, min, i)
    print(aList)

def swap(aList, x, y):
    temp = aList[x]
    aList[x] = aList[y]
    aList[y] = temp

selection_sort(aList)
```

Comment: You don't need a swap function. `aList[x], aList[y] = aList[y], aList[x]`

Comment: Hint: The error is on this line: `for j in range(len(aList)):` Which elements of the list does it iterate over?

Comment: You set `j = i + 1` and changes it when you go to this loop: `for j in range(len(aList)):`

Comment: one mistake you are repeatedly doing is that if the variable names are same, they are not necessarily the same variable.

Comment: @deadcode What do you mean by that? Are you talking about the name `aList` being used in two different functions? Because apart from that, there are no duplicate variable names.

Comment: @ArthurTacca yes that and the `j = i + 1` . I don't see the use of this line unless the intention was to somehow effect the j in the next loop. Forgive me if I am wrong

Comment: Maybe this is overly pedantic, but I found your first comment confusing because `j` is the same variable being assigned a new value, not a "different variable".

Comment: yes I agree, I like to be pedantic about such things too. My bad :)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, it seemed to me that you used `j = i + 1` in hopes that it will somehow effect the `j` in the subsequent loop, but it is a different variable. So is the `aList` in your function definition, it can have any name, even aList. Your `j` is iterating over the entire list again and again and hence the `min` or the smallest value is carried wherever `i` goes (so it ended up in the end). So what you need to do is make your second loop only iterate through the next items after `i`.

```
aList = [1,5,6,3]

def selection_sort(List):
    for i in range(len(List)):
        min = i
        for k in range(i,len(List)):
            if List[k] < List[min]:
                min = k
        swap(List, min, i)
    print(List)

def swap(List, x, y):
    temp = List[x]
    List[x] = List[y]
    List[y] = temp

selection_sort(aList)
```

Comment: @philsegut you're welcome. If this answers your question, accept this as the answer (by clicking on the tick) to consider it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
def select_sort(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        min_loc = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(l)):
            if l[j] < l[min_loc]:
                min_loc = j
        l[min_loc],l[i] = l[i], l[min_loc]
    return l
```